# Symfony/ VichUploaderBundle: DirectoryNamer

Tags: php, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I´m trying to implement a DirectoryNamer, but unfortunately this results in an error message and I don´t know what to do next.

The Controller (excerpt):

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($image);
        $em->flush();
        //...
}
```

The DirectoryNamer Service Class:

```
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\DirectoryNamerInterface;

class ArtistDirectoryNamer implements DirectoryNamerInterface
{
    public function directoryName($image, PropertyMapping $mapping) {   
        return $image->getArtist()->getId();
    }
}
```

The VichUploader Configuration:

```
vich_uploader:
db_driver: orm
mappings:
    upload_artists:
        uri_prefix:         /upload/artists
        upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/upload/artists
        directory_namer:    macms_admin.artist_directory_namer
        namer:              vich_uploader.namer_uniqid
        inject_on_load:     false
        delete_on_update:   true
        delete_on_remove:   true
```

... and the reulting Error Message:

> Compile Error: Declaration of ArtistDirectoryNamer::directoryName() must be compatible with Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\DirectoryNamerInterface::directoryName($object, Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\PropertyMapping $mapping)

What´s wrong with my code? Until I´ve implemented the DirectoryNamer, the upload worked fine and the files have been stored in '/upload/artists'.

Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forgot the `use` statement for the `Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\PropertyMapping` class?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I added the use statement (and the namespace as well ;) ) and now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Due to K-Phoen - here´s the working solution:

```
namespace Acme\Project\AdminBundle\Services;

use Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\DirectoryNamerInterface;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\PropertyMapping;

class ArtistDirectoryNamer implements DirectoryNamerInterface
{
    public function directoryName($image, PropertyMapping $mapping) {   
        return $image->getArtist()->getId();
    }
}
```